# Getting undefined error when submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am essentially trying to have a form. Then when you submit, it just prints out `value` what you have selected from the drop down. However all I get is `undefined undefined`

```html
<form action="items" method="get">
Fruits
<select name="fruits">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="all-fruits">All Fruits</option>
</select>

<br/>

Vegs:
<select name="vegs">
    <option value="carrots">Carrots</option>
    <option value="peas">Peas</option>
    <option value="Lettuce">Lettuce</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="show_selection()"><br>
Your Selection: <span id="result"></span>

<script>
    function show_selection() {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('fruits').value + " " + 
        document.getElementsByName('vegs').value;
    }
</script>
```

If you select `All Fruits` in the `fruits` section and `Peas` in the `vegs` section, it should print `all-fruits peas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `document.getElementsByName` returns a [node-list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) collection. This means that you can potentially have multiple elements in this collection which are retrieved from your HTML because they all have the same `name`. Thus, if you wish to only get the one element from this collection, you need to use index `0` to target that element.

See working example below:

```html
<form action="items" method="get">
Fruits
<select name="fruits">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="all-fruits">All Fruits</option>
</select>

<br/>

Vegs:
<select name="vegs">
    <option value="carrots">Carrots</option>
    <option value="peas">Peas</option>
    <option value="Lettuce">Lettuce</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="show_selection()"><br>
Your Selection: <span id="result"></span>

<script>
    function show_selection() {
        let selectedFruit = document.getElementsByName('fruits')[0].value;
        let selectedVeg = document.getElementsByName('vegs')[0].value;
        
        if(selectedVeg == "peas") {
          selectedVeg = "Peas!!!";
        }
        
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = selectedFruit + " " +selectedVeg;
        
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:** If you look at the snippet above you will see that I have stored both of the selected options in their own variables. You can then use an `if` statement to check if the variable is equal to a particular string (eg: `peas`) and then change the variable accordingly so that it updates the outputted text.

Another solution to this is to give your `select` element an `id`. As `id`s must be unique for each element, you can then use `document.getElementById` to get one single element rather than a collect of elements:

```html
<form action="items" method="get">
Fruits
<select id="fruits">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="all-fruits">All Fruits</option>
</select>

<br/>

Vegs:
<select id="vegs">
    <option value="carrots">Carrots</option>
    <option value="peas">Peas</option>
    <option value="Lettuce">Lettuce</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="show_selection()"><br>
Your Selection: <span id="result"></span>

<script>
    function show_selection() {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById('fruits').value + " " + 
        document.getElementById('vegs').value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am new to javascript, I just have a question, how can I get a value and put it in an if statement. Like if `peas` is chosen then print out `Peas!!!!!!!!`

Comment: @Marshall You can store the selected options in variables and then change them if they're equal to a particular value. See my edit in my answer

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to know how I can assign it to a variable!

Comment: @Marshall no worries !! :D

Answer (score 1):

When getting elements by name it returns array of nodes. So you just need to change `document.getElementsByName('fruits')` to `document.getElementsByName('fruits')[0]` and `document.getElementsByName('vegs')` to `document.getElementsByName('vegs')[0]`.

So your code will look like this:

```
<script>
    function show_selection() {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('fruits')[0].value + " " + 
        document.getElementsByName('vegs')[0].value;
    }
</script>
```